# The time period when my money will be double

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given an amount is £P over a period of time, n years at r% interest. How can I calculate the year when £P will be double?

The well-known compound interest formula, $$P\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^n$$

Comment: I just need an approximate answer

Comment: What about writing the equation and use logarithms

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $t$ is small the [rule of $70$](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/rule-of-70.asp) tells you the doubling time is approximately $r/70$. So investing at $7\%$ annual interest doubles your principal in $10$ years.

The correct calculation calls for solving
$$
2 = \left( 1 + r  \right) ^n
$$
for $n$ in terms of $r$, so
$$
n = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln(1+r)} .
$$

The rule of $70$ follows from  $\ln(2) = 0.6931 \approx 0.7$ and that when $r$ is small $\ln(1+r) \approx r$.

Answer (score 1):

The amount by which $P$ is multiplied is $\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^n$. Hence the money doubles when this factor is equal to $2$, that is, when
$$\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^n = 2.$$

Solving for $n$ (*make sure you understand how to do this using logarithms!*), this gives $$\boxed{n = \frac{\log 2}{\log\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)}}.$$

The boxed formula tells you how many years ($n$) it takes for the money to double. Given a value of $r$, you can use your calculator to obtain the value of $n$.